# Does Java mandate garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Does JLS/JVMS mandate garbage collection? Presumably any sane implementation would have garbage collection, but can insane ones nonetheless qualify as spec-conforming JVMs?

Comment: JVM implementors doesn't implement "insane" implementation ..

Comment: @hagrawal, insane implementations can be useful for research purposes. E.g. one that performs all allowed transformations under the JMM even if they are nonsensical can be used to implement a hostile VM for the purpose of testing thread-safety of libraries.

Comment: @the8472 Still it doesn't make it "insane". More it more like a personal implementation, not a distributed implementation, and in personal implementation one can do anything but it will not be qualified for any tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garbage collection is required by the spec.

Quoting the JVM Specification, "[Heap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.3)":

> The Java Virtual Machine has a *heap* that is shared among all Java Virtual Machine threads. The heap is the run-time data area from which memory for all class instances and arrays is allocated.
>
> The heap is created on virtual machine start-up. Heap storage for objects is reclaimed by an **automatic storage management system (known as a *garbage collector*)**; objects are never explicitly deallocated. The Java Virtual Machine assumes no particular type of automatic storage management system, and the storage management technique may be chosen according to the implementor's system requirements. The heap may be of a fixed size or may be expanded as required by the computation and may be contracted if a larger heap becomes unnecessary. The memory for the heap does not need to be contiguous.

Comment: Interesting, so the JLS makes a distinction between automatic storage management and garbage collection, but the JVM specification says they're synonymous.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Yeah, I noticed that too, comparing your quote to mine.

Comment: The bracketed (known as a garbage collector) could be interpreted as spillage from what they had in mind for the implementation into the spec. The following sentences backpedal immediately "assumes no particular type of automatic storage management". Somewhat contradictory overall.

Comment: Automatic storage management could conceivably mean "expand the heap whenever needed, throw OOM when no more virtual address space is available, never reclaim". After all things like `System.gc` or finalizers make no guarantee when GC happens, it could be deferred indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

The exact quote from the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/) is:

> The Java programming language is a relatively high-level language, in that details of the machine representation are not available through the language. **It includes automatic storage management, typically using a garbage collector**, to avoid the safety problems of explicit deallocation

Comment: Thank you for this reference. I am accepting the other answer only because I can accept only one.